# Redis: OK to put on a multi-homed system?

Tags: redis

We want to use a single Redis server for servers that span two subnets.

If we put Redis on just subnet A, the servers on B will have to go across a router to get to redis.

Our thought is to make the Redis server multi homed (multiple nics), attached to both subnets A and B.

1) Will this work?
2) Will Redis then attach to both IP's?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that belongs to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the bind address in the redis configuration file (bind parameter).

Now if you comment out the definition and do not provide a bind address, Redis will listen to its port on all the interfaces (i.e. it will listen to 0.0.0.0).

I did not try, but I would say a configuration with 2 addresses should work.